# How can I set a display resolution of 1366x768 in a Acer Aspire One ZG5?

Tags: 12.04, display, resolution, acer, aspire-one

How can I set a display resolution of 1366x768 in a Acer Aspire One ZG5 within Ubuntu 12.04? The only resolutions available are 1280x768 and 800x600.

Comment: Perhaps this can be solved by setting some sort of overscan effect?
The annoying part of this resolution is that even some of the simple setup windows in Ubuntu, are to big for this resolution. The bottom half is outside the screen and can't be reached with the mouse. Therefore it takes guesswork to tab down to the Apply or Okay button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: It is not possible to set the display resolution to 1366x768 in a Acer Aspire One ZG5.  The Acer Aspire One ZG5 does not support resolutions higher than 1024x600.

As you have 1280x768 listed under System Settings > Displays, it is very likely you do not have an Acer Apsire One ZG5.  Ubuntu 12.04 will correctly detect the display's native resolutions and populate the settings appropriately during installation.

Source: http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/netbook/0000/Acer/AspireOneAOA150/AspireOneAOA150sp2.shtml

Answer (score 1):

I believe what he is talking about is DOWNSCALING on the ZG5.

There is a program for windows that downscales 1024x768 on a realtime 1024x600 display.
It is called a1ctl.

The result is that the picture is not that good.  The upside is that you can see the entire normal screen which is important for some programs and some games.  That is why a downscaling program for ubuntu, any flavor of ubuntu, linux is so important.

In the future I may be working with small tft screens with omap processors for robotics.  If UBUNTU has downscaling I would rather go with them rather than creating custom installations of Gentoo!!!

Answer (score 0):

Click on the cog in the top right hand corner and select Displays.  Then the Resolution drop down should include the valid resolutions.

Comment: I only have two options: 1024x768 (4:3) and 800x600 (4:3). The question is How can I add additional resolutions?

Comment: Are you sure the screen supports that resolution?